# How to join CSS transformY and jQuery UI sortable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a task box that MUST to have limited height. Why? Because I have a button that scroll down tasks by CSS transformY and it let me to see more tasks that were hidden before. In my fiddle I created 2 examples. First is before tapping "scroll button" and second is after 3 tapes (so we can see 3 more tasks).

Then I made that boxes sortable. And problem is that after "scrolling" dragged element is jumping up.

Please try it yourself, to drag and drop tasks in first box and in second:

```js
$(".barbox").sortable();

$("#scrolled").children(".bar").css("transform", "translateY(-153px)");
```

```css
.barbox{
  height: 307px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1{
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.bar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h1>Example 1:</h1>
<div class="barbox">
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 1.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 2.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 3.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 4.</div></div> 
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 5.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 6.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 7.</div></div> 
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 8.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 9.</div></div>
</div>
<h1>Example 2:</h1>
<div class="barbox" id="scrolled">
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 1.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 2.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 3.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 4.</div></div> 
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 5.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 6.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 7.</div></div> 
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 8.</div></div>
  <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 9.</div></div>
</div>
```

How to come up with that? How to join transformY and jQuery UI sortable?

Comment: The calculations done to define the position of an element while dragging don't take the transform you've applied into consideration. It's probably better to try to do that some other way, or change the way the position is being calculated while dragging.

Comment: I tried to add margin-top to dragged element but it didn't react.

Comment: Can anybody help please? It is very important for me.

Comment: Can't you just move `.barbox` instead of all `.bar` inside?